# How to connect socket.io to MongoDB server side of react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, websocket, rsocket-js

I have done a project with React which uses ExpressJS to create a server-side already one and use MongoDB there. How to implement socket.io in the message component of the client site and server side or how to connect socket.io on the server side?
The server-side image is given below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please privilege copy and pasting into code blocks instead of attaching images. It makes it easier to read and more searchable.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.